# Do historians agree that most wars are caused by religion?

Tags: war, historiography

I'm not a historian, but this is a very common claim that crops up in debates over God's existence and religious scripture. What is the opinion of the community of professional historians?

Comment: Most wars are caused by a conflict of interest, whether that interest has a veneer of belief (religious, philosophical, ideological) or not.

Comment: While it might motivate the commoners to fight a war they don't otherwise care about, religion is generally a cover for some other more pragmatic reason to go to war.

Comment: @Bregalad Agreed - the "primarily opinion based" close reason doesn't make sense; its perfectly possible to objectively survey historians for a consensus. Or, for the underlying question, to go through the wars of history one by one and tally up their causes by categories. Several studies did just that.

Comment: @Bregalad Agreed about the close vote (and that the reason doesn't make sense). However, downvotes might be for other reasons (e.g. lack of evidence of prior research).

Comment: Marxist historians agree that wars are caused by property & exploitation of the proletariat.  Liberal historians agree that wars are caused by conservatives.  Conservative historians agree war is caused by liberals and everyone agrees to hate Tom Lehrer.  Any statement that begins, "All X agree... " Ilia rhetorical, not academic.  The only response to such statements is to order another pint & change the topic.

Comment: @Kai: "Never in history has the world been less religious, never in history has mankind had more potential for destruction". The question is about real wars fought, not potential for destruction. Arguably, despite contrary belief, never in history we have lived in more peaceful times (see e.g. Steven Pinker).

Comment: @Scrontch that is a hopelessly naive view, I would say that almost all of the worst genocides in the existence of this world has happened in the 20th century

Comment: The late Robert Heinlein, a graduate of the United States Naval Academy once opined that all wars were, at root, caused by population pressure.  He added that this was true even for religious wars, but you had to dig into trade routes and resources to see it.  I once queried the head of the History department at his alma mater about it, did not really get an answer.  I observe that the Naval Academy is a very good school, and understanding the causes of war is very much part of the education of an officer.

Comment: War is fought over resources.  Religion is used to convince people who will less materially benefit from its spoils to fight.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86416/discussion-on-question-by-tomislav-ostojich-do-historians-agree-that-most-wars-a).

Comment: Which historians? How many have to agree before the answer is yes?

Comment: @Semaphore - counting wars one-by-one might not be that easy anyway: Later in Thirty years war, that started with religious pretexts about the freedom of religion here in Bohemia, catholic France supported protestant countries to weaken Hapsburg monarchies. Though you could argue, that 30YW were actually several separate conflicts, further muddling your counts.

Comment: I'm also curious about wars for multiple reasons (or with multiple stated reasons) -- does the Reconquista count as a religious war? A war for territory growth? A war for a strategic location? (possibly a bad example because it wasn't really a single war, but you see my point)

Comment: Why only historians?  It seems similar as asking if doctors agree if death happens to all of us

Comment: often times Religion is used to justify acts of war or to pretty much convince people to go to war, however the underlying cause of those wars are actually to gain territory, resources or simply to exterminate competition.

You'd be surprised how enthusiastic people get just by yelling "God demands it!" or "God wills it" 
So more accurately religion is a tool. But not the actual cause.

Comment: Many if not most wars are started over resource conflicts, whether it be water, raw materials, land, or people (workers, slaves, etc.). Quite often religion is used to stir up sentiment against the enemy in the population, but that's using religion as an excuse rather than the root cause.

Comment: is it a coincidence that this kind of question appears just some decades after atheist regimes (commies) killed +100M people?

Comment: @Luis no.......

Answer (score 313, accepted):

**The idea that "most wars are caused by religion" is trivially false**. From what I can see, this is a rhetoric rooted in a critique of theism, rather than serious historical analysis. Even a casual survey of history shows most wars had little to nothing to do with religious differences - [according to quasi-original research on Wikipedia, only 6.98% of known conflicts were religious](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Religious_war#cite_note-Axelrod,_Alan_2004-1).

To my knowledge, there has been no formal polling of academics on the subject. Nonetheless, we may infer a prevailing opinion of historians from their research. While existing works only examine the modern period, they all point to the same conclusion: **Territory, not religion, is the most common cause of war.**

[image]
<sup>Territorial disputes is **the** leading cause of war throughout the centuries. Source: Holsti, Kalevi J. *Peace and War: Armed Conflicts and International Order, 1648-1989.* Cambridge University Press, 1991.</sup>

(Although the works cited below are time-limited, there is no obvious reason to believe the underlying patterns of wars would be significantly different in the pre-modern world. Even the Muslim Conquests or the Christian Crusades were isolated and punctuated by many non-religious conflicts. The [European Wars of Religion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_wars_of_religion) were a historical aberration, not the norm.)

---

First, let's consider the analysis of modern wars by [Evan Luard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evan_Luard). He divided post-1400 history into five periods and noted that the primary causes of war shifted over time. To briefly summarise, his findings were:

1. Age of Dynasties (1400-1559): conflicts over **territory** were linked to **dynastic claims**.
2. Age of Religion (1559-1648): **religious conflicts** triggered conflicts over **territory**, but non-religious wars of opportunity also took place.
3. Age of Reason (1648-1789): religion vanished as a cause of war, to be replaced by conflicts over **strategic territories** and dynastic succession.
4. Age of Nationalism (1789-1917): wars became increasingly linked to **identity** and national independence - **territories** were a common cause of war in colonial empires, Latin America as well as the Far East.
5. Age of Ideology (1917-1986): political **ideology** dominated the causes of war.

However, other historians have noted that:

> [W]hile Luard declines to nominate territory as the dominant factor throughout the centuries, nevertheless, **territorial issues keep cropping up in his analysis** - in connection with issues of succession, dynastic disputes, or state creation. Thus, Luard probably underestimates the importance of territorial issues in fomenting wars.
>
> <sub>Cashman, Greg. *What Causes War?: an introduction to theories of international conflict.* Rowman & Littlefield Publishers, 2013.</sub>

---

Luard's analysis is evaluative rather than qualitative. For the latter, consider the survey by Kalevi Holsti in 1991. He divided the post-Westphalia history of conflict into five periods and attempted to classify their causes into rather narrow categories. The results were as follows:

[image]

As you can see,

> "Territorial issues" are the only ones that have been among the dominant issues in each of the periods [1648-1714, 1715-1814, 1815-1914, 1914-41, and 1945-89]. In four of the five periods, more wars have involved territorial issues than any other kind of issue, exceeded only in 1815-1914 by the "maintain the integrity of state/empire" issue, which is an issue obviously related to territorial concerns.
>
> <sub>Vasquez, John A. *The War Puzzle Revisited.* Cambridge University Press, 2009.</sub>

In contrast, as you can see from the table, religion began at only 6% and has steadily declined since then. This is dwarfed by the number of wars over control of land or resources, even in our current period when territorial conflicts are at a historical low. As the following table demonstrates that territorial disputes constitute the vast majority of all wars since Westphalia:

[image]
<sup>Source: Vasquez, John A. *The War Puzzle Revisited.* Cambridge University Press, 2009.</sup>

---

Of course, Holsti's analysis began only after the European Wars of Religion, identified by Luard as the same period religious differences were a leading cause of war. Nonetheless, the fact that religion all but disappeared as a cause for war in the centuries since is strong prima facie evidence against the claim that it could have caused "most wars".

Fundamentally speaking, wars are nearly always driven by some kind of self-interest. Land, historically near synonymous with wealth, was of prime interest to most polities. Consequently - without discounting the genuine effects faith may have on true believers - religious (as well as ideological, nationalistic, etc) reasons are just as likely a *source of legitimacy* for using force, as it is a motivation in and of itself.

Comment: Great answer! Do you have any insight on how many of the non-religious wars used religion to sell the war to the people of the countries involved? I mean, while the actual reason for the conflict may not have been religious, religion may have been used to popularise and/or justify the war. If we count such cases as religious wars, would that change the answer in any significant way? (Also, you have a typo and I don't have the rep to fix it: _The European Wars of Religion were a **historian** aberration_, should be _historical_.)

Comment: @terdon Thanks for the catch, fixed. As for your question, I do not believe that would significantly affect the conclusion, no. For the most part, religious wars *already are* wars sold to the populace / armies / foreign states using religious justifications, rather than being genuinely motivated by religion. That's the point being hinted at regarding Laud - if the wars really weren't about territory, why did religious conflict fight over territories? Without being unduly cynical, the line between religious wars, and non-religious wars justified by religion is very thin.

Comment: Indeed; in fact I'd be surprised if we could find _any_ war that was actually and wholly fought for religious reasons. Fair enough.

Comment: And even in those 7% of wars "caused by religion", I would bet many of them were in reality caused by territorial or financial disputes, and religion was just a good pretext to declare war or to motivate the soldiers (but the war would have started regardless).

Comment: Seconding @vsz here. For instance, the 30 Years War (touched on in this answer) was clearly religious, right? Well, what made it truly long and bloody was the involvement of Catholic France *against* the Catholic Hapsburg Empire. At first by subsidizing other parties, but eventually directly. That was pretty obviously not religiously motivated.

Comment: @T.E.D. Yeah, that's what I'm trying to communicate. As I said in the conclusion and the comments above, religion is an ideological mechanism for *legitimising violence*, but the motivations for resorting to violence in the first place is nearly always rooted in some kind of self-interest. That said, while the French highjacked the war for geopolitical reasons, the first half of the 30 YW was clearly religious in nature. Dismissing religion as a factor in all wars is as untenable as blaming it for most wars.

Comment: I'm going to use that phrase, "quasi-original research," so I can get by the folks who shutdown immediately after the word Wikipedia.

Comment: @Semaphore re: your second comment. My personal opinion would be that the lines between most allegedly separate causes of war are in practice highly blurry.  The only reason two countries may be separate in the first place (and proceeding to engage in territorial wars) might have been long-ago religious divisions. Which are/were in turn tied up with cultural/ethnic/ideological identities etc etc...

Comment: Not to downplay the substantial research done here, but I feel like "territory" is a bit of a non-answer when it comes to war and its motivations, given that war is an armed struggle over territory almost by definition. The Mexican-American war is about as close to a war fought over pure territorial issues as you'll find, but even that is caught up in weird messianic state populism notions. The almost-war we had over Crimea looks like a territorial dispute, but there you'll find economic and ethnic undertones too. Everybody wants to rule the world, but you need a good reason to send tanks.

Comment: Is there a specific reason that the transition from Age of Nationalism to Age of  Ideology falls in the middle of WWI?

Comment: @JAD The Russian Revolution created the world's first Communist state that year, and allowed the remaining Allies to be reframed as democracy fighting autocracy.

Comment: @Semaphore gotcha, thanks for the clarification!

Comment: The answer fails to take into account that territorial disputes may very well be religious based.  For example "This holy land named Jerusalem is ours".
Nor does it take into account that a war may be caused by multiple issues, any one of which removed may result in no war; but only one issue is recorded as the cause.

Comment: @UKMonkey Yeah no, this proves you obviously didn't read the answer. The very first paragraph suggests 7% of known wars have religious causes. The second section reports that religion triggered many wars between 1559 and 1648. The second figure lists religion as accounting for 6%, 3% and 4% of war causes in three different periods. And religion is discussed again in the conclusion. **Again, just because religious wars may involve territory, does not change the fact that the vast majority of wars did not involve religion at all.**

Comment: Shitty TL;DR: People like to have stuff. Often, people are willing to use force to get stuff. Sometimes they are willing for religious reasons. Sometimes they use religious reasons as a justification when they were already willing. The bottom-line is having a unifying ideology (whether that was part of your original motivation or not) helps convince a broader audience to use force to get stuff. In a few cases (percentage-wise), that ideology is religious.

Comment: The Crusades are generally considered "religious wars", but remember the bit about the 4th Crusade, where the Crusaders decided their fellow Christians in Constantinople were easier pickings?   Dig into a lot of the actions of the actual crusaders and it looks a lot more like people looking for power and glory than people driven by religious conviction.

Comment: Even crusader wars were plunders. On their way back, they plundered orthodox monasteries.

Comment: @T.E.D. you could argue that 30YW was actually a series of interrelated conflicts.

Comment: @Edheldil ... and you’d be right.  However, you’d also be right to point out that the European wars of religion had much more to do with money and politics than they did with religion.

Comment: Is this study relevant or useful: http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/shared/spl/hi/world/04/war_audit_pdf/pdf/war_audit.pdf

Comment: @SYS_V Good find. Although they only reviewed a handful of wars, these findings reinforces other studies about how religion is mostly not the cause of wars - I see only 7 wars where they scored religion's involvement at 3/5 or more.

Comment: The second table is interesting, but I would like to have the total number of wars considered in each period. For instance, there was '-' (aka 0%, or at least less than 1% I suppose) *secession/state creation* wars in 1815-1917, but I find it hard to believe considering the desintegration of the Ottoman Empire and the US civil war. Also, it might be interesting to weight the wars by their intensity (mesured e.g. by the casualties).

Comment: @Evargalo The Ottoman independence wars most likely fell under "National liberation/state creation"; the consensus is that the American Civil War was fought over slavery, so that probably got put under "ideological liberation". It would be interesting to see the result by casualties **if** calibrated to the level of casualties for conflicts of the era (so you're not just measuring how much more deadly wars were in different centuries), but that's an immense work way out of scope for an answer imo.

Comment: @Smeaphore But how does Kalevi Holsti make a distinction between "National liberation/state creation" and "secession/state creation" ? I am afraid this might be just about the outcome of the war, not its causes: e.g., *if* the Confederate States had gained independance, wouldn't they be considered a 'nation' today ? Or Timur got its independance, so Timur's war might be called 'National liberation', while Ajeh hasn't, so Ajeh's war might be called 'Secession' ?

Comment: @Evargalo That's just nonsense. The Ottoman minorities have national identities and a history of statehood for centuries. Greeks, for instance, has existed for millennia before any Turks set foot in Greece. Meanwhile the Confederates didn't even speak a different language to the Union. There are always going to be fringe cases, but there is an intuitive and obvious distinction between these categories. Anyway, what's the point of quibbling over this? As noted he was intentionally being pedantic; the finer points of his analysis on what drove state creation has got nothing to do with religion.

Comment: Thank you for this answer.

Answer (score 91):

> Do historians agree that most wars are caused by religion?

No, historians have not formed such a consensus.  There are numerous scholarly works reaching back 5 millennia demonstrating that this belief is apocryphal.  This work demonstrates religion historically has played a small role in wars either as a major or minor cause.

> **[Is Religion the Cause of Most Wars?](https://www.huffingtonpost.com/rabbi-alan-lurie/is-religion-the-cause-of-_b_1400766.html)**
>   History simply does not support the hypothesis that religion is the major cause of conflict. The wars of the ancient world were rarely if ever, based on religion.
>
> ...an objective look at history reveals that those killed in the name of religion have, in fact, been a tiny fraction in the bloody history of human conflict. In their recently published book, “**[Encyclopedia of Wars](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0816028516)**,” authors Charles Phillips and Alan Axelrod document the history of recorded warfare, and from their list of 1763 wars only 123 have been classified to involve a religious cause, accounting for less than 7 percent of all wars and less than 2 percent of all people killed in warfare.

A Different source: **[The Encyclopedia of War](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/The+Encyclopedia+of+War,+5+Volume+Set-p-9781405190374)** edited by Gordon Martel says if one excludes 40 little understood internal wars fought by the Islamic Caliphate religious wars drop to only 3% of all wars in its pages.

**[Institute for Economics and Peace issued a report](https://www.str.org/blog/is-religion-the-cause-of-most-wars#.W_5RcS3MxQM)** in 2014 which further supports these numbers.

So Historians, reviewing 5 millennia worth of war, have reached the opposite conclusion.  Religion is a reason for war, but not the reason for most wars.

Wars are often blamed on a single reason but typically caused by a combination of reasons.  Yes Religion is among the reasons historically countries go to war, it is even a primary cause of some conflicts like the **[Crusades](https://www.history.com/topics/middle-ages/crusades)**, **[Thirty Years' War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thirty_Years%27_War)**, and **[the Lebanese War 1975-1990](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebanese_Civil_War)**  Religion is not the primary reason historically speaking for most wars.

**[Common (major and minor) Reasons for War:](https://owlcation.com/social-sciences/The-Main-Reasons-For-War)**

> 1. Economic gain: (oil, natural gas, nickel, etc ).

- **[Anglo-Indian Wars (1766-1849)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anglo-Indian_Wars)**
  A series of wars fought by  British East India Company leading to the colonization of India.
- **[The Winter War (1939-1940)](https://www.ibiblio.org/hyperwar/ETO/Winter/USMA-Finnish/index.html)**
  The Soviet Union invaded Finland in order **[to control the nickel mines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nickel_deposits_of_Finland)**.
- **[The American Revolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/France_in_the_American_Revolutionary_War)**
  For America a revolutionary war, for the French who allied with the United States against Britain it was fought over trade routes and commerce.  The French involvement began first with a trade agreement with the Colonies and only after that was signed a declaration for French military assistance against Britain.
- **[WWII, in the Pacific](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pacific_Ocean_theater_of_World_War_II)**
  The Japanese attacked Pearl Harbor in order to seize commodities in Asia.
- **[Iraq's invasion of Kuwait](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invasion_of_Kuwait)**.
  Iraq invaded Kuwait to seize the oil and alleviate their war debt with the Kingdom.
- **[South China Sea](https://www.cfr.org/interactives/global-conflict-tracker#!/conflict/territorial-disputes-in-the-south-china-sea)**
  The ongoing dispute with China over the South China Sea,  It's about 11 billion barrels of untapped oil and 190 trillion cubic feet of natural gas estimated to exist in the disputed territory.

> 2. Territorial Gain

- **[Mexican-American War (1846-1848)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mexican%E2%80%93American_War)**.  It was a land grab.  The slogan manifest destiny spoke to the United States desire to become a two Ocean country. (Atlantic and Pacific).   The War facilitated the United States purchase of what is now the American South West as well as California.
- **[Arab-Israeli War or "Six Day War" (1967-1988)](https://www.economist.com/special-report/2017/05/20/how-the-1967-war-changed-the-shape-of-israel)**
  After years of small-scale conflict when Egypt blockaded the straight of Tiran, Israel attacked gaining the Sinai Peninsula, the West Bank, and Golan Heights effectively tripling the size of the Israeli state.
- [Russia's invasion of the Crimea (2014)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annexation_of_Crimea_by_the_Russian_Federation)

> 3. **[Nationalism](https://polisci.ucla.edu/sites/default/files/u245/andrew_bertoli_paper_05-01-17.pdf)**

- **[World War I](https://alphahistory.com/worldwar1/nationalism/)**

> 4. Revenge

- **[World War II (invasion of France by Germany)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_France)**
  One of Hitler's stated reasons for invading France was to reverse the Treaty of Paris which ended WWII which he felt treated Germany unfairly and was a factor in Germany's impoverishment in the interwar period.  He met with French representatives in the same train car which hosted the WWI summit which ended the Great War and even had the memorial in Paris to the historic treaty blown up.

> 5. Civil Wars and or Revolutions
>      Fought over disputes which arise internally to countries or over a change of leadership.

- American Civil War (1861-1865)
- Russian Civil War (1917-1923)
- Spanish Civil War (1936-1939)
- Korean War (1950-1953)
- French Revolution (1789-1799)
- Haitian Revolution (1791-1804)

---

**Addressing the Comments**

> **Steven Burnap**
>   "Lebensraum" was an explicit aim of Germany in WWII. The Japanese actions that lead to WWII in China, as well as their invasion of the Philippines, was also very much about gaining territory. Though this really just goes to show that history usually doesn't fit into neat categories. "Religious war" being a neat category.

@Steven Burnap,  Hitler's book Mein Kampf, was written in two volumes, The first volume, entitled **[Die Abrechnung](https://www.britannica.com/topic/Mein-Kampf#ref279066)** (“The Settlement [of Accounts],” or “Revenge”), calls for revenge against France for its destruction of Germany's first and second Reichs.

Specifically, Hitler discusses the 30 Years War in which Germany's first Reich (**[Holy Roman Empire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holy_Roman_Empire)**) was eviscerated by the French in 1648, with the **[Peace of Westphalia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peace_of_Westphalia)**.  Secondly and famously the treatment of Germany in the surrender documents ending WWI which both impoverished Germany in the interwar period and ended Germany's second Reich, Imperial Germany ()1871–1918 ending Kaiser Wilhelm and the end of WWI.

In Hitler's first volume he dedicates the title to the major theme of his foreign policy.   Revenge against France.   To your point Hitler also discusses **"Lebensraum"** in his first volume,  the need for "Living Space" for Germany and says Germany will gain this in the east at the expense of the Slavs:  Czechoslovakia, Poland,  Belarus, Ukraine, and Russia.

A major stated goal of Hitler's Third Reich was to address the downfall of the first and second German Reichs at the hands of the French.  In June of 1940, [Hitler drove this point home](https://www.nationalgeographic.com.au/videos/apocalypse-world-war-i/hitlers-revenge-treaty-3641.aspx) with what National Geographic calls his Revenge Treaty in which France surrenders to Germany June of 1940.  Hitler held the surrender ceremony in the same boxcar in which France had hosted Germany's surrender in WWI.  Designed the entire venue to embarrass the French referencing Germany's previous treatment by the then victorious French in WWI.   Just after this ceremony Hitler personally ordered Frances **[Rethondes Clearing](https://armistice-museum.com/destruction-of-the-clearing/)** memorial to WWI's German surrender blown up with dynamite.

As for Japan's war in China, I don't dispute what you say.  What I said was Japan attacked the United States, Dec 7, 1941, over oil.  The attack was to clear obstacles to Japan's real target of that offensive, the Dutch East Indies -- now Indonesia.

On July 26, 1941, the American President Franklin D. Roosevelt signed an executive order which froze Japan's assets in the United States and cut Japan off from 93% of their Oil all of which was imported.  Japan had about a year and a half of oil in their strategic reserve and after that, they would not be able to continue their war in China.  Japan attacked Pearl Harbor on Dec 7, 1941; and invaded Dutch East Indies Dec 8th to secure what was then the 4th largest oil exporter in the world behind the U.S., Iran, and Romania and guarantee Japan would be energy independent.
Japan also gained access to rubber production facilities and iron mines both of which were important, but oil was the most important material they seized in the days after Pearl Harbor.

> **[Japan's Dutch East India Campaign](https://www.britannica.com/topic/Mein-Kampf#ref279066)**
>   Access to oil was one of the linchpins of the Japanese war effort, as Japan has no native source of oil;[15](https://www.history.com/topics/middle-ages/crusades) it could not even produce enough to meet even 10% of its needs,[13](https://owlcation.com/social-sciences/The-Main-Reasons-For-War) even with the extraction of oil shale in Manchuria using the Fushun process.[16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thirty_Years%27_War) Japan quickly lost 93 percent of its oil supply after President Franklin D. Roosevelt issued an executive order on 26 July 1941 which froze all of Japan's U.S. assets and embargoed all oil exports to Japan.[17](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebanese_Civil_War) In addition, the Dutch government in exile, at the urging of the Allies and with the support of Queen Wilhelmina, broke its economic treaty with Japan and joined the embargo in August.[15](https://www.history.com/topics/middle-ages/crusades) Japan's military and economic reserves included only a year and a half's worth of oil.[13](https://owlcation.com/social-sciences/The-Main-Reasons-For-War) As a U.S. declaration of war against Japan was feared if the latter took the East Indies, the Japanese planned to eliminate the U.S. Pacific Fleet, allowing them to overtake the islands; this led to the attack on Pearl Harbor.

Comment: Some of these are rather disputable. For example, wwii and invasion of France by Germany happened after the war already started. It was a logical pre-emptive strike after the war has already started. While Germany may had motivation to revenge, the actual conflict is clearly territorial and triggered by invasion of Poland. East was the main target, fighting UK and France was just a necessity after the Strange War.

Comment: @Greg I think that you are refering to what in English is named the [Phoney War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phoney_War)

Comment: @Greg To expand... Germany and France have been at loggerheads since at least the Franco-Prussian War with recidivism and revanchism for past losses. Now it was Germany's turn. Germany (or at least the party in power) wanted revenge for WWI. It also wanted the territory it lost to Poland and France for economic and nationalistic reasons. And it needed to knock out its hostile neighbor to the west: security. The invasion of France was nationalism, revenge, territory, economic gain, and security.

Comment: "Lebensraum" was an explicit aim of Germany in WWII.  The Japanese actions that lead to WWII in China as well as their invasion of the Philippines was also very much about gaining territory.  Though this really just goes to show that history usually doesn't fit into neat categories.  "Religious war" being a neat category.

Comment: @StevenBurnap I responded to your comments at the end of my answer.    Greg, I would just say that territorial gains in the East and revenge goals in the West are not mutually exclusive.   Hitler expressed decades long interest in both.

Comment: There's good reason to believe though that the Nazis would have been happy if England (and by extension France) would have stayed out of the war with Poland, so while it's fair to say that war with France was obviously something Hitler was preparing for, and which ultimately he was working towards, it's not that clear that the actual war aorse simply because the Nazis wanted revenge. After all, France declared war on Germany (in response to the invasion of Poland), not the other way round.

Comment: Saying  a war has a religious cause or revenge cause as the above answer states doesn’t imply it’s the only cause.

Comment: Small quibble over the Winter War: the USSR wanted more than just nickel, but also power plants and a strategic buffer around Leningrad. Ultimately it was also an attempt to expand the Soviet sphere of influence by subjugation (same as with the Baltic republics and the partition of Poland with Germany).

Comment: @SPavel,  You are right.   I changed my answer to make it more clear. I wasn't trying to suggest the various examples of conflicts were motivated only by economic, territorial, nationalism, or revenge; but that in these Wars there was some of that type of cause. Just like the sited material found 123 examples were religion played some cause in 1763 wars.. not 123 wars exclusively caused by religion.

Comment: "No historians have not formed such a consensus." There should be a comma between "no" and "historians".

Answer (score 35):

In addition to the good answers given already, I'd like to point out that wars are typically not mono-causal. Very often, several reasons as well as causes (i.e. sparks that light the fire) come together for a war to start.

In addition, the reasons given in public are often not the actual reasons. There are a number of explicitly religious wars (the Islamic conquests of Europe, the European answer aka The Crusades). In many other wars, religion played a role in the "us vs. them" sense - religion is one of the factors that bind people together and separates them from other people, just like language, skin colour, etc. It is easier to start a war against "others" than against "like us".

And finally, there are many parties involved in wars. The head of state might declare the war, but there are so many different people with interests involved and for some of them a financial profit might be important, for some of them territorial gains, and for some of the religion. These goals also change during the course of a war or in parts of the war. For example, JMS gave "revenge" as the reason for WW2, but the attack on Russia had other reasons, and the war in North Africa was purely for resources. Meanwhile, WW2 also had the Asian part with Japan as the aggressor, which again had different reasons to start their part.

Identifying one reason for a specific war is most likely an oversimplification. So the question as phrased doesn't even make sense because it asks to identify a mono-causal relationship which in reality does not exist.

Religion certainly played a role in most pre-modern-times wars, though it was more often used as a cover for more simple desires (taking land, resources, disputes over hierarchy or succession, etc.) than the other way around.

I'm not a professional historian, just interested in history. From what I've found in books and other resources, historians would not, in general, agree that anything is the #1 source of wars, simply because wars are not so easy. That begins with the difference between reason and cause - between what the background of the conflict is and what often small spark caused the conflict to finally erupt. WW1 is a good example for that, it was caused by the assassination of Archduke Franz Ferdinand, but if that hadn't happened, something else would have most likely caused the war that everyone was pretty much waiting for.

That makes it difficult to ascertain if religion contributes to that background. For the king or whoever, it is certainly easier to start a war if he can also add religious reasons to the motivation. The 30 years war is an example where religion played a major role, but many other often regional causes added to the mix until the whole thing exploded.

Comment: The Islamic Conquests and Christian Crusades were still just a disguise for an (attempted) land grab.

Comment: @Hosch250 Depends on the participants. Certainly there were many who had no prospects of inheritance at home, and went on the Crusades hoping to become a lord in the East. At the same time, many kings and lords financed, organised, or participated in the Crusades without a realistic hope of gaining possessions so far from their own lands. Some were probably making political calculations, but it's dubious you can wholly discount genuine religious motivations for everyone.

Comment: Agreed. But then you can't discount genuine religious motives for everyone in *any* war.

Comment: @Hosch250 - land grab or not, religion was not only a thinly veiled excuse in these cases. Especially the islamic expansion was part of the religion from the very start, Mohammed himself started this and the European wars were just the conclusion of that process. The Crusades wanted to liberate the holy lands, which by purely economical reasoning was a questionable motive, you need at least a combination with religion to make the whole thing make sense. In more simple terms: In other conflicts you can remove religion and apart from some propaganda nothing goes missing. In these two cases, not.

Comment: @Tom By purely economic reasoning, whoever controlled the "holy lands" controlled European land-based trade with Asia.

Comment: @Hosch250 - I'd say you need to control a couple more places for that to work.

Comment: @user151841, the Silk Road route varied over the years, but it generally entered the Mediterranean either through Constantinople or through Egypt, not through the Holy Land.

Comment: @Mark Having trade skip over the Byzantines/Ottomans was a long sought-after goal of various European nations...

Comment: @user151841 - the silk road never went through the holy land. Its southernmost terminator was Damascus, well north of Jerusalem. But neither were chokepoints, you'd have to go into the interior, at least to Palmyra, to get a chokepoint. Crusaders never went that far. The to me most likely non-religious interpretation of the Crusades is a counter-attack against muslim invasion, as the orthodox head of Constantinople had plead for help from the pope - his religious enemy, so the situation must have been dire indeed. But that is a different discussion.

Comment: @Hosch250 well, the Islamic Conquest **was** a land grab, not even disguised. It was all about conquering the entire world for Islam - but that's the point: **For Islam**, not for any ruler or people, but explicitly for religious purposes.

Answer (score 8):

> **Q** Do historians agree that most wars ***are*** caused by religion?

Most historians agree that most wars cannot be described with a monocausal reason.

There is a big bunch of problems associated with asking the question in this way. Definitions, conceptualisations, perspective, timeframe and grammar are all undetermined or off. Is this about whether the claim as such is true or about an assumed majority opinion of historians; now or previously?

Just a thought: Who started the [Global War on Terrorism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/War_on_Terror)? The Americans? Al-Qaeda? For what reasons (aka "cause")? Is religion the main causative motivator for the American led forces? Is it for "the other side"? Perhaps a minority might answer yes to religion as a motivator for American forces, but surely most will accept the narrative that bin-Laden and his followers were primarily religion motivated? Or do they emphasise his apology that he became offended when American troops were stationed on Saudi-Arabian soil, making this again about land and territory, 'holy' or not? But perhaps it is different yet?

> Bush’s war openly remains a cosmic battle between nothing less than the transcendent forces of good and evil. Such a battle is necessarily unlimited and open-ended, and so justifies radical actions–the abandonment, for example, of established notions of civic justice at home and of traditional alliances abroad.
>   <sub>[James Carrol: "The Bush Crusade. Sacred violence, again unleashed in 2001, could prove as destructive as in 1096.", The Nation, September 2, 2004](https://www.thenation.com/article/bush-crusade/)</sub>

Historians do not always agree on a subject matter of the past. Historians diverge very widely if it is about how to apply those insights from the past to the present day. If you want to know historians view on what the reasons for war ***are***, then a number of people will say this or that.
Samuel Huntington, for example, views that [civilisations or cultures are clashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clash_of_Civilizations) –– and were for some time now. The main differentiator of a culture by this definition is its religion. Therefore, those sympathising with the Huntington school assume that most wars are caused ultimately by religion.

But leaving aside the semantics over grammar and resultant meaning of "are caused", it seems that there still is an anachronistic and eurocentric vision dominating the way this question was to be answered here.

This question is about religion in general, not about Christianity, Islam or any form of monotheistic religion? Then religion is a prime motivator for ingroup-outgroup behaviour. It represents the core of order for any civilisation against the chaos. And therefore for war in general. We do not have to reduce "religion" to "any form of some belief" to approach the problem. Otherwise, it gets trivial: "*we believe* that this strip of land belongs to us, *we believe* to need that etc"; *we believe* capitalism to be so much better for mankind".

Going into a structuralist or functionalist mindset we might say that sure, religion needs a base from which to perform. So a religious motive is in reality about power, and that is about power over the inhabitants, and that is over the lands on which those inhabitants live. Muslim expansion is then nothing about any form of to invent or develop a form of Islam, just land grabbing of Arab conquistadors who happened to eventually provide an ideological superstructure to justify the new rule and system of power distribution and organise a changed set of alliances between rulers and ruled.

If we ask the propagandists *for* war from the past, then we have to first reflect on the nature of state and religion in general. It was indistinguishable. Romans fought a *bellum sacrum*, Christians had Crusades against Muslims, [Albigensers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albigensian_Crusade), [Prussians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_Prussians); earlier Charlemagne brought Christianity by sword to the [Saxons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saxon_Wars), native Americans; Muslims conquer India, Hindus fight the Muslims, [English](http://www.oxfordscholarship.com/view/10.1093/acprof:oso/9780199253487.001.0001/acprof-9780199253487) Christians wanted to mission the world with tea, opium and Christianity for the [betterment](https://theconversation.com/the-gift-of-civilisation-how-imperial-britons-saw-their-mission-in-india-80302) of humanity. Muslims have their jihad to this day. The Incas were weakened when Christian Spanish arrived to conquer those pagans because of a civil war to determine who really was the legitimate descendant of Inti, the sun.
 [Mayans had their star wars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_war), [Aztecs flower wars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flower_war). The latter from a modern perspective for no particular reason, other than to capture people to be used in human sacrifice. That looks as if there is nothing else but a religious motivation in those kinds of wars. Romans inquired the [auspices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auspice) before going to war than performed a religious ritual on the mars field, performed *[evocatio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_ancient_Roman_religion#evocatio) deorum* before the enemy's city gate, then captured the city god and added it to their own pantheon. The [Hittites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hittite_mythology_and_religion) performed exactly likewise.

Is there any war or warlike conflict in the [Bible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Bible_and_violence) or the early Jewish history that is not *entirely* about religion? The taking of the promised land, the wars against Jericho, Ai, Israel & Judah, the [Maccabean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maccabees) Revolt, the at least three full [Jewish Wars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_Jewish%E2%80%93Roman_War) against Rome?

It can very well be argued that it is universally true, that before the 'modern state' and the ideas of separation of church and state, religion was one prime cause for *all* the wars.

Or it is true that rulers and generals always lie. That what *really* was or is the cause is always something else. All [marxist historians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marxist_explanations_of_warfare) would agree to that. And Clintonistas as well. [It's the economy, stupid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%27s_the_economy,_stupid).

The prime motivation as stated by instigators might then be "religion", although it *really* is about something else: the means to rule; in form of land, labour means of production. Those who follow Claude Levi-Strauss will of cause know it even better than that: all human conflict can be broken down to disagreements over the [exchange of women](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchange_of_women). Let's not forget [reductionist](https://owlcation.com/social-sciences/The-Main-Reasons-For-War) [explanations](https://web.stanford.edu/~jacksonm/war-overview.pdf) like those from an offshoot of psychoanalysis. War is an illness in society and all of society's illnesses can be [cured by achieving a proper orgasm](https://www.theguardian.com/books/2011/jul/08/wilhelm-reich-free-love-orgasmatron). –– If that sounds ridiculous, then looking for mono-causality of war, for any war, in the thousands of years for its history is likely as well.

---

> Religion is one of the most powerful forces in human history, and its power makes itself known in ways both dramatic and intimate in our world today; unfortunately, the impact of religion is often divisive and violent. If we want to truly understand religion’s ability to influence human events, we need to grasp its psychological bases, and to take a scientific approach to religious psychology means using our best theories of how the mind works.
>   <sub>John Teehan: "In the Name of God. The Evolutionary Origins of Religious Ethics and Violence", Wiley-Blackwell, 2010.</sub>
>
> <sub>Martha T Nussbaum: "Democracy, Religious Violence, and
>   India’s Future",</sub>
>
> This is one of history's ironies, that although religion has been used to justify violence, violence can also empower religion. Perhaps understandably. therefore. in the wake of secularism, and after years of wait· ing in history's wings, religion has made its reappearance as an ideology of social order in a dramatic fashion: violently. In time the violence will end, but the point will remain. Religion gives spirit to public life and provides a beacon for moral order. At the same time, it needs the temper of rationality and fair play that Enlightenment values give to civil society. Thus religious violence cannot end until some accommodation can be forged between the two-some assertion of moderation in religion's passion and some acknowledgement of religion in elevating the spiritual and moral values of public life.
>   <sub>Mark Juergensmeyer: "Terror in the Mind of God: The Global Rise of Religious Violence", University of California Press: Berkeley, London, 2000.</sub>
>
> To understand the role of religion in the emergence of American empire, we need to look beyond any simple opposition or interaction between “church” and “state” and see instead how the construction and corrosion of power and authority have operated across sectors of society, especially around apparently “secular” categories in which the displacements of religious logic have most 
>   effectively operated under assertions of innocence, purity, or transcendence.  ose categories through which the material origins of desire have most consistently been compressed and displaced in America are age, race, and gender, as expressed in the culture in various identities associated with collectives like the nation or, now, an empire.
>   <sub>Jon Pahl: "Empire of Sacrifice. The Religious Origins of American Violence", New York University Press: New York, London, 2010.</sub>
>
> Violence served to uphold the Egyptian concept of correct order, known as *Ma'at.* Some violence, such as sacrificial servant burial, did so by ensuring that correct social order continued in the next life. Most violence in the service of the order was aimed at the destruction of chaos, or *Isfet.*
>   <sub>Kerry Miles Muhlenstein: "Violence in the Service of Order: The Religious Framework for Sanctioned Killing in Ancient Egypt", Dissertation, University of California: Los Angeles, 2003.</sub>
>
> Much has been written about the relationship between religion and violence, and much of what has been written is aimed at determining whether, how, and why religion causes violence.  This book has a different goal. Followers of many different religions who commit violent acts seek to justify these by appealing to religion. I aim to understand how such justifications proceed; and how they do, or do not, differ from ordinary secular justifications for violence. I will show that religious justifications for violence generally exemplify the same logical forms as ordinary secular justifications for violence. I will also show that many religiously based justifications for violence are as acceptable as rigorous secular justifications for violence, provided that crucial premises, which religion supplies, are accepted. Religious believers are able to incorporate premises, grounded in the metaphysics of religious worldviews, in arguments for the conclusion that this or that violent act is justified. I examine three widely employed types of premises that appear in such arguments. These are: appeals to a state of “cosmic war,” appeals to the afterlife, and appeals to sacred values.
>   <sub>Steve Clarke: "The Justification of Religious Violence", Blackwell: Chichester, 2014.</sub>
>
> The Enduring Relationship of Religion and Violence / Violence and Nonviolence at the Heart of Hindu Ethics / Buddhist Traditions and Violence / Sikh Traditions and Violence /  Religion and Violence in the Jewish Traditions / Religion and Violence in Christian Traditions /  Muslim Engagement with Injustice and Violence / African Traditional Religion and Violence / Religion and Violence in Pacific Island Societies /  Violence in Chinese Religious Traditions
>   <sub>Mark  Juergensmeyer & Margo Kitts & Michael K. Jerryson: "Violence and the World’s Religious Traditions. An Introduction", Oxford University Press, 2017.</sub>

Answer (score 6):

Other answers are justifying a straight "no", but what else is going on in the "critique of theism" mentioned by Semaphore?

The atheist philosopher Tim Crane addresses, in his book "The Meaning of Belief" (2017, Harvard University Press) claims of this kind that are made by certain atheist critics of religion (so, his subject is not any supposed consensus among historians). Spoiler alert: his view of attempts by famous atheists like Dawkins or Hitchens to analyse religion is not broadly approving. What does he say about claims that religion is wholly or mainly responsible for war and other violence? p120-122:

> The violence and destruction imposed in the name of Christianity has a long history: the medieval Crusades ... [4 further examples]; and we could go on, of course. Put like this, you can see why people say that the history of Europe in the second millennium AD was a history of religious violence.
>
> Against this has to be placed the equally terrible history of large-scale nonreligious violence and cruelty. Examples easily spring to mind: the killing of the Central American natives by the conquistadors, the slave trade, ... [4 further examples]. And then of course there are the other monstrous crimes of the twentieth century: the Nazi Holocaust and the mass killings by the communist regimes in China and the Soviet Union. As with religious violence, it seems all too easy to find examples.
>
> Some writers more sympathetic to religion attempt to argue that those examples show that religion is not really the source of the world's problems, and that even so-called religious conflicts are not really religious underneath. ... Karen Armstrong traces the origin of human violence to the beginnings of agrarian societies and the accumulation of wealth...
>
> The account I sketched of identification in Chapter 3 of this book indicates one other place where an explanation of of religious violence that is not specifically religous might begin. The tendency of human beings to form groups explicitly defined in opposition to others, which then seek the destruction and subordination of the other groups, is one of the characteristic features of many recognizably human societies. But facts like these do not mean that religion has no special, distinctively *religious* role in explaining episodes of violence. ... The question is rather, what is this role.

He goes on to point out that even wars that some attribute to religion are not necessarily caused by any theological content of the religion. p132:

> It would be entirely incorrect, even frivolous, to suggest that the filoque clause is one of the factors that influenced the war between the Serbs and the Croats in the 1990s. And yet, if we are to look at the theological origin of the separation of the Roman and the Orthodox Churches, this would have to be mentioned (among many other details) ... yet it is plain that this doctrine has nothing more to do with the war than the fact that the Serbs use the Cyrillic alphabet and the Croats use the Latin alphabet.

So, what is there to religion other than theology? Well, that's the major part of the book, and his view is that religion consists of group identification, together with the "religious impulse" toward something that transcends normal life, connected by a shared notion of what specific things are sacred. Hence, there are other ways that religion could be a factor than just theology. p134 returns to the causes of religious violence:

> I mentioned three further conjectures about the sources of religious violence and conflict: (2) nontheological but distinctively religious aspects of religions; (3) the element of identification; (4) other nonreligous aspects of human psychology, society and culture.

p143:

> Religion is one factor, without doubt. But is it the most fundamental or important factor? How can we go about answering this question? Is there even any need to answer it? ... The extreme violence in these cases is often explicable in terms of the tendency of identification (religious or not) to exclude and discriminate against others; the violent content of some religious texts; or the struggle for power, supremacy, or autonomy among competing religious groups--in addition to human motivations and desires (for example, revenge) that are intelligible independently of anything to do with religion.

There's plenty more detail, but his gist is that what constitutes religion "causing" violence (or a war in particular) is by no means a simple or settled issue. That being the case you can't really have a simple, settled view of whether religion is uniquely culpable among other factors.

So the claim that "most wars are caused by religion" may not even be intelligible. Do most wars have religion among their causes? Are most wars caused solely by religion? What aspects of religion can be included or excluded in the assessment of whether religion caused something? You're going to do a very different analysis according to how you interpret the basic structure of the question, never mind your actual historical opinion about the causes of every war.

Answer (score 3):

Historians, by and large, agree that most wars fought for **resources**  and thus are caused by the greed for worldly or physical gain, be it land, women or money. See: ***"Encyclopedia of Wars,"*** by **Charles Phillips** and **Alan Axelrod**.

However, in order to motivate the masses, they used religion as a motivational tool. This still works today, given how many use Christianity as a motivation to be a conservative. This is ironic, given that that religion was essentially a **rebel** movement, against the Roman Empire and decidedly **not** a conservative cause.
Therefore, while religion itself might not cause wars, it does acerbate them because religion is used as a ***justification***. Joan of Arc, the Civil War, Colonial wars would not have had this effect had it not been for the religious motivation. And it's doubtful that Joan of Arc would have gone to Germany or Africa to fight perfidious Albion.

As a side effect of triumphantly decrying that religion is NOT a cause of wars, some play the fake victim card: "Oh, us poor Christians, who are oppressed by the evil atheist hordes."

Comment: I am unaware of *any* religious arguments used to gain support for or provide justification of  the American Civil War or the American Revolution.

Comment: @Michael: not necessarily a "cause", but you're only asking for an argument. There were theologial debates over slavery, and Franklin proposed in 1776 "Rebellion to Tyrants is Obedience to God" as the motto for the US Seal, but they went with "E pluribus unem". That would seem to be a religious point (albeit that's not a fully-developed form of it) in favour of the revolutionary war. It would be astonishing if *literally no* religious argument was used by *anybody* in favour of (and against) anything important.

Comment: @MichaelJ. Eeehm, your reasoning is fallacious, therefor invalid. It has no value. Consider that I didn't claim religion was a **NECESSITY** to start a war. And further: Did no-one claim in either of those wars that "God was on their side" ? I'm gonna take a wild guess </sarcasm> and say that both sides in both wars claimed exactly that.
2,1 seconds of googling will find you Southern claims that slavery was A-OK because of the "Curse of Ham".  In typical southern conservative fashion, even THAT was a lie: Ham wasn't black, and his descendants weren't Africans.

Comment: @ GwenKillerby, you made a rather gratuitous assertion that "religion" was used to justify the American Revolutionary War and the American Civil War. I challenge you to prove that assertion, otherwise, your assertion is nothing other than your own personal opinion

Answer (score 2):

I have never read such a theory, by any historian.  This is likely because few real historians have ever made the claim.

I think we can easily see why that is: To be "most" it must be over 50%.

But not all religions are warlike.  And not all warlike religions can be used to justify/launch wars.

Buddhism, Hinduism, Taoism are non-warlike religions.  And they can most certainly not be used to justify wars (the god of those religions can't be owned by a group of followers.  And those gods never made any promises, and never demanded the followers to find new followers)

Shintoism is warlike religion but it can't be used to start wars.  because it isn't a god-owning religion.

Mesoamerican religions are not overly well understood, but given they didn't launch a holy war against the foreign invaders it seems pretty clear that holy war wasn't their thing.  Native americans also don't have a war like religion.

Right there, that's more than 1/2 the world, and probably more than 1/2 the wars ever fought.

Then there are a few religions that are both warlike and war justifying.  This is made possible by a custom made god that institutionalizes racism, makes land grant, and gives a religious mandate to spread the truth of 'love', 'peace', 'hope', 'chosen' and 'faith' to anyone lacking in 'love', 'peace', 'hope', 'chosen' and 'faith'.  And if the infidels, heathens, nonbelievers, etc. refuse to accept the truth, the followers are encouraged to convert them, by force if necessary.

But even then, not too many of the wars by the adherents were actually fought in the name of those religions.  And most of the biggest ones were all religion free.  Napoleonic War, Franco-Prussian War, WWI, WWII, the 100 years war, the 30 years war, the crimean war, etc.  That doesn't mean each side didn't bring their holy men with them to war, to ask their god to smite down those other guys in the opposing army.

So I would say a tiny percentage of wars are caused by religion, the rest are caused by kings playing the game of thrones.

Comment: +1 but there's actually been some wars with religious characteristics involving Buddhists, for example Ikko-Ikki; also Shintoism isn't inherently more warlike than other paganistic faiths, you're probably thinking of State Shintoism which actually considered itself distinct from "Religious Shintoism".

Comment: In Mesoamerica there were [flower wars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flower_war) - in which religious motives might have been one of the reasons.

Comment: flower wars?  that sounds a lot like american football meet gladiator...  or something...   And since they aren't here to explain themselves (thanks to religious people from Europe), I guess we will never really know what they were about, or whether religion was a part of it...

Comment: @sofageneral, the debate among historians is whether religion was the dominant / only cause for flower wars.  Historians do not doubt that religion was a component of the flower wars.

Comment: To say "Buddhism, Hinduism, Taoism are non-warlike religions ... Shintoism is warlike religion ..." is a myth all by itself. References?

Comment: it is a myth?  why?  because you say it is?  Do you have any references to support your theory?   (too can play this silly game)  Everyone knows Bushido is a warrior code steeped in the tradition of Shintoism (itself a mix of zen-Buddhism, chinese Confucianism and Japanese traditions, which is where the warlike elements came from)

Comment: Given that the worst ethnic-religious cleansing since Yugoslavia is now being perpetrated by the Buddhist Burmese, makes claiming that Buddhism is non-warlike pretty nauseating. It was instigated by a Buddist MONK! A good example of Buddhism being used as a motivator to slaughter Rohinga. (Cue "No True Scotsman" fallacy in 5, 4, 3...).
ANY group identification will be used to justify slaughter, religion is no exception. In this case, the usual "Muslims raped a girl" lie was used. That the veracity was questionable isn't even the point. The point was that Muslims were blamed AS MUSLIMS.

Comment: GwenKillerby   have you considered the possibility that what you are staitng is fake news by god owners invented to make other god owners feel better about their god owning religions

Comment: And how are the Rohingyas getting genocided?  https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/worldviews/wp/2018/01/10/in-a-first-burmese-military-admits-soldiers-killed-rohingya-found-in-mass-grave/?utm_term=.bea20ed0a7f4    may be 10 in a mass grave.. and people want to call it genocide, ethnic cleansing, or what have you?  that's not even a bad weekend in tijuana.  (It would be a bad weekend in chicago. but not unheard of)

Comment: The approximately quarter of  million Japanese Christians exterminated by a movement led by Buddhist monks might disagree with the proposition that Buddhism is any less warlike than Christianity. Neither religion is warlike at all taken on its own. That you can call Christianity warlike and think Buddhism or Hinduism isn't reveals a severe Eurocentrism in your education.